# XML Parsing using apache xmlbean

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, xmlbeans

I have an XML file without a namespace and wanted to add the namespace while parsing it. I am using the Apache XMLBeans API to parse the XMLs:

```
<Parent 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://myschema.com/ns/parent"
    xmlns="http://myschema.com/ns/parent" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I am trying to set the namespace using following code snippet but somehow it is not working, schema is not added in XmlOptions.

```java
XmlOptions opts = new XmlOptions();
HashMap<String, String> suggestedPrefixes = new HashMap<String, String>();
suggestedPrefixes.put("http://myschema.com/ns/parent", "xmlns");
suggestedPrefixes.put("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xmlns:xsi");
opts.setUseDefaultNamespace();
opts.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(suggestedPrefixes);      
opts.setUseDefaultNamespace();
opts.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(suggestedPrefixes);

XmlObject xmlObj = XmlObject.Factory.parse(xml, opts);
```

Not sure if this is the right way to set the schema.

Comment: The question is confusing. Do you want to *add* missing namespaces to an XML document without any namespaces using your parser — or do you want to *configure* your parser to deal with the existing namespaces in your XML? Because the second thing is possible, the first thing is not. In other words, show your actual input and the wanted output.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I want to add the missing namespace to the XML document.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. An XML namespace is not some weird-looking attribute. You cannot "add" it. Namespaces are integral parts of the node, you need to create actual new nodes and throw away the old ones if you want nodes in a different namespace.